# make bootable iso from linux from scratch

Tags: iso, lfs

i have created linux from scratch which has / in /sdb2 and /boot in /sdb1 and swap in /sdb3 , now i want to create a iso , how do i do it?

size of
1. / = 25 GB
2. /boot = 100 MB
3. /swap = 2 GB

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean here. It seems like you've installed Linux from scratch on your computer. Typically an iso file is used for imaging an install disk, but you already seem to have the OS installed. What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a tool such as [Linux Respin](http://www.linuxrespin.org/) ([source code](https://github.com/ch1x0r/LinuxRespin)) or [Linux Live Kit](https://www.linux-live.org/) which you can use to build a bootable ISO (if your Linux from scratch distro supports it). You can search for a tutorial, like [this](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/make-your-very-own-customized-linux-distro-from-your-current-installation) one.